# Displaying the title of a BibTeX entry when using the APA document class

Tags: bibtex, apa-style

When referring to a book, I can use `\citeA[p.~10]{AuthorYear}` to display the authors name and other citation information. Is there a convenient way to have the in-text citation display the title of a book?

E.g. `\citetitle{AuthorYear}` will display *The Book Title*.

Comment: Please provide an example. Based on the documentation and incompatibility with `natbib` I think no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that AuthorYear is your bibkey:

```
\documentclass[noapacite]{apa}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{texbook,
   author = "Donald E. Knuth",
   title= "The {{\TeX}book}",
   publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
   year = 1984
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citetitle}{}{\printfield{title}}{;}{}
\begin{document}
\citetitle{texbook}
\end{document}
```